# Streamline select code to find attributes that exist for a given set of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, form-helpers

Statuscategory has_many statuses and statuses belong_to statuscategory.

Here's my db schema:

```
create_table "statuses", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "statuscategory_id"
end

create_table "statuscategories", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I want to run a search on another model, Borrow, that has status as an attribute. But I don't want to just do a `collection_select` on `Status.all`. Instead, I want to run a search that acts like a filter, that pulls only the statuses that exist in the existing records of Borrows (only the unique statuses, there might be 8 Borrow records all under "Searching", all I care is that the status is "Searching"). Below is the code that I've got, which works, but I feel like it's far from the right way of doing things:

```
<%= f.select :status1_eq, Status.where(id: Borrow.all.pluck("status1").uniq).pluck("name"), {default: @q.status1, include_blank: @q.status1.nil?} %>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the cause here as you have mentioned:

`Statuscategory` `has_many` `statuses` and `status` `belong_to` `statuscategory`

And you are trying to get `statuscategories` while one status belongs_to one `statuscategory`. So you should be doing something like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :status1_eq, Statuscategory.where("name LIKE ?", "%1%"), :id, :name, {default: @q.status1, include_blank: @q.status1.nil?} %>
```

Otherwise `status` will have only one `subcategory` related to it and there would be no gain doing by your process.

Tell me if it solves the problem and feel free to ask for more.

Comment: Ok sorry, I should have clarified the question. Just added some edits, please take a look now!